# What is the default font displayed in bokeh plots?

Tags: bokeh

I could not find this information in the documentation. Does anyone what the default font is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helvetica, though different sizes and styles are used in different places.

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/d213e3d755f09f57d2a58da3c1dcba939a3b90bf/bokeh/core/property_mixins.py#L164